# MVC3 InnerException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Problem: How to display exception detail (InnerException?) in my DbError view in MVC3

The code below produces a null reference when trying to display the InnerException.

```
   <p>@Model.Exception.GetType().Name<br />
@Model.Exception.InnerException.Message.ToString()<br /> <!-- null reference! -->
thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName</p>
```

In my global.asax

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
        {
            ExceptionType = typeof(DbException),
            // DbError.cshtml is a view in the Shared folder.
            View = "DbError",
            Order = 2
        });
```

code originally from http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all exceptions have an inner one. Make sure that the provided exception actually has an `InnerException`. If it doesn't, simply print out the details of the provided exception instead (which you generally should do, the `InnerException` simply details the error mentioned in the root exception).